# Bordism and complex $K$-theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

In work related to positive scalar curvature, *Stephan Stolz (Ann. Math.)*, but later  *Stolz-Kreck* ($HP2$ bundles  and Elliptic cohomology) introduced a version of Real connective  $K$-homology by considering spin cobordism, localizing at the prime $2$ and  then killing  classes which  are determined  by  bundles  with  fiber  $HP2$.
Is  there  an  analogous  version  for  complex (connective) $K$-homology?

Comment: Maybe you are interested in
Hopkins, Michael J.(1-MIT); Hovey, Mark A.(1-YALE)
Spin cobordism determines real K-theory. 
Math. Z. 210 (1992), no. 2, 181–196. 
which proves there is an iso
$MSpin^c_*(X)\otimes_{MSpin^c_*}K_*\to K_*(X)$ ?

Comment: And, as Hopkins-Hovey discuss, for the complex orientation $MU \to KU$ this goes back to Connor-Floyd in 1966, see here: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cobordism+theory+determining+homology+theory